# Using PyCharm IDE for Power BI

Tags: pycharm, powerbi, data-visualization

I am playing around with Power BI and trying to use Python to do the coding. However, I ran some issues of connecting Power BI and PyCharm. It fail to create the PythonEditorWrapper.PY when I try to use PyCharm to edit the Python script. Error message is below:
[error message from PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXeXy.png)

So how can I change the location to create this PythonEditorWrapper.PY ?